# Set datetime in SQL

Tags: asp.net, sql, datetime

I'm wanting to set the current time i my database

My column is a "datetime" format

My insert SQL is as follows.

```
// Set last login
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
string insertSQLDet = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[user] (last_login) VALUES (" + date + ") WHERE user_id=" + user_id;
```

But I get an error saying I have incorrect near "WHERE". Can anyone see what's wrong?

Comment: From _"wanting to set"_ , I presume you are looking to **update** your records. You should rather opt for an update statement instead of an insert statement in that case. Also, you may need single quotes (') around your date to make it work. Best though would be to use a parameter based SQL as pointed out in some of the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess! you want to update the `last_login` field so use the `UPDATE` statement and always use parameters.

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
string sql = "UPDATE [dbo].[user] SET last_login=@date WHERE user_id=@userid";
using(SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand(sql,conn))
  {
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@date",SqlDbType.DateTime).Value=date;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@userid",SqlDbType.VarChar,20).Vaule=user_id;
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
   }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't even think of that. :)

Answer (score 1):

`INSERT` statements do not allow predicates, because you are not selecting anything. Did you mean to issue an `UPDATE` statement?

```
"UPDATE [dbo].[user] SET last_login = " + date + " WHERE user_id = " + user_id
```

Also, I'd strongly encourage you to [use parameters to provide values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254953.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

What RDBMS are you using? MSSQL or MySQL? you dont have to pass to a parameter if you want to get the datetime of the server. there is a function that will automatically get the server's datetime.

for MSSQL Select GetDate() as ServerDate
for MySQL Select TIMESTAMP as ServerDate

Answer (score 0):

You are not selecting rows from any other table. You are manually giving the values that why you can not use where clause in this situation.

If you are trying to update then following query will work for you,

```
"UPDATE [dbo].[user] SET last_login = " + date + " WHERE user_id = " + user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass datetime as a parameter. You can just select it at server inside the insert statement. Also use parametrized queries to bind your parameters.

```
string qry="INSERT INTO [dbo].[user] (last_login) VALUES  ((SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) WHERE user_id=@userId"
```